# I am getting a blank screen after opening the laptop lid (resume from standby)

Tags: 10.10, suspend, suspend-resume, thinkpad

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat. I am getting a blank screen after opening the lid of my IBM R51 ThinkPad, which forces me to restart the system. Suspend mode is not working in my laptop. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

- Have you tried moving your mouse a bit after resuming - on my machine I get a black screen after resuming and I have to move my mouse a bit to get the login screen.
- Does hibernate work properly?
- What is your ACPI state? Can you switch it around and try again?
- Are you running a stock kernel?

The last two comments in [this bug entry](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/568711) indicate that the R51 does not resume from suspend properly, although it did work in previous versions. What you could do is follow these two debugging guides and submit your results to the bugs:

- [Debugging Kernel Suspend Hibernate Resume](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspendHibernateResume#Suspending)
- [Debugging Kernel Suspend](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend)

Also, can you try the one suggestion from the bug above? I mean this one:

> I also have this on a second tier laptop. And it only started about 2 weeks ago. If I go to *system* > *preferences* > *power* > *on AC power* and switch from *suspend when lid closed* to *hibernate* and then back again, make as default, it works sometimes.